# Propagate the visibility from parent to child views

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a Relative layout as a part of tha larger layout.
The child views of relative layout is Linear Layout(which holds custom widgets) and custom widget

overview.xml:

```
<FrameLayout>
    <CustomScrollWidget/>
    <LinearLayout>
        <include layout="@layout/layout_header"/>
        <CustomWidget/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <View/>
</FrameLayout>
```

layout_header.xml:

```
<LinearLayout id= "header">
    <View/>
    <RelativeLayout>
        <Child views>
    </RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
        id="abc"
        visibility="gone">
        <LinearLayout>
            <CustomWidget/>
            <CustomWidget/>
            <CustomWidget/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <CustomWidget/>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Java code:

```
RelativeLayout rel;
View viewHeader;

final View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.overview, container, false);  
viewHeader = root.findViewById(R.id.header);  
rel = (RelativeLayout) viewHeader.findViewById(R.id.abc);
if(true){
    rel.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
else{
    rel.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

The child views of the relative layout id "abc" are always visible. how can I fix this.
I want the child views to be gone, when the visibility of the relative layout is set to gone.

Comment: You must be doing something else wrong. If you hide the parent view than all the children will be hidden as well.

Comment: You are right, my gradle was not in sync and was taking the old data. Now when I fixed the sync issue it worked. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you hide parent/root (cotaniner) layout children of this layout are always not visible also.

Comment: Relative layout is part of another layout, may be if I past the whole layout might get an idea

Comment: You are right, my gradle was not in sync and was taking the old data. Now when I fixed the sync issue it worked. Thanks